# Is it possible to use a C++ named module without an object file?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

I'm trying to compile a simple empty module example (using gcc 11.2):

```
// my_module.cc:
export my_module;


// main.cc:
import my_module;
int main() { return 0; }
```

Using these compilation commands:

```sh
g++ my_module.cc -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c
g++ main.cc -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts my_module.o
```

This compiles fine.

However, even though the module is empty, I need the module's object file (`my_module.o`) when compiling `main.cc`, because the linker wants the function `_ZGIW9my_moduleEv`. I'm assuming this function is meant to perform initialization for static variables or something similar, as it will call `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0` if I define static variables in the module.

My question is, does every module really need an object file? Is there any way to mark a named module as "doesn't need initialization, all my functions are inline"?

I think that header units could be used like this, but they're supposedly meant only as a transitory solution and have other downsides like macro hygiene.

Comment: "*My question is, does every module really need an object file? Is there any way to mark a named module as "doesn't need initialization, all my functions are inline"?*" What does it matter? If it only calls the function if the module has static variables... then it won't call it if the module doesn't. So... it's irrelevant. Just include the .o file and move on.

Comment: FWIW there seems to be a GCC issue discussing this without any conclusions https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=98364